# Using a variable to declare a worksheet by its number in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables, integer, worksheet

Good evening. I am desperate for some help with a short piece of VBA Code I am writing.

```
Public TFOCUS As Integer ' Creates TFOCUS, which is the worksheet in focus
Public RFOCUS As Integer ' Creates RFOCUS, which is the row in focus
Public CFOCUS As String  ' Creates CFOCUS, which is the column in focus
Public RECORD As Integer ' Creates RECORD, wich is the row that is having the record written to

FILEPATH.Worksheets(TFOCUS).Range(Cells(RFOCUS, B)).Value = Worksheets(3).Range(Cells(RECORD, A)).Value 'copies focus EmpID to destination
FILEPATH.Worksheets(TFOCUS).Range(Cells(4, CFOCUS)).Value = Worksheets(3).Range(Cells(RECORD, B)).Value 'copies focus Course to destination
FILEPATH.Worksheets(TFOCUS).Range(Cells(RFOCUS, CFOCUS)).Value = Worksheets(3).Range(Cells(RECORD, C)).Value 'copies focus Date to destination
CFOCUS = CFOCUS + 1 'moves focus to next column
RECORD = RECORD + 1 'creates next record
```

FILEPATH is set to the path of an external Excel workbook. In this instance, TFOCUS is set to 1, RFOCUS is set to 5, CFOCUS is set to "Q", and RECORD is set to 1.

The purpose is to copy records from an external excel document into the active spreadsheet, and reformat them by moving the cell contents about. This will be used to move multiple sources, and will have to deal with every tab in every source document (which could all be named something different).

The issue I am having is that I am recieving a **Runtime Error 13: Type Mismatch** error when compiling, on the following line:

```
FILEPATH.Worksheets(TFOCUS).Range(Cells(RFOCUS, B)).Value = Worksheets(3).Range(Cells(RECORD, A)).Value 'copies focus EmpID to destination
```

I am assuming that this is either to do with the use of TFOCUS as an integer or FILEPATH as a file path. Can anyone suggest:

- What exactly the mismatch is
- If it is because of using Worksheets(TFOCUS), any way I can reference the worksheet by its number in the tab order using a variable?
- Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing us where/whether the variables are assigned, but...

> ```
> Public RFOCUS As Integer ' Creates RFOCUS, which is the row in focus
> Public CFOCUS As String  ' Creates CFOCUS, which is the column in focus
> ```

Try declaring `CFOCUS` as an `Integer`. Or better, as a `Long`, so that your code works beyond row 32767 (the `Integer` type is 16-bit and signed, so 32768 is an overflowing value).

Also, if `FILEPATH` is a `String`, then your code can't work:

> *FILEPATH is set to the path of an external Excel workbook.*

> ```
> FILEPATH.Worksheets(TFOCUS)
> ```

It should be a `Workbook` object.. but then the identifier you're using is very confusing.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FILEPATH)

wb.Worksheets(TFOCUS).Range(Cells(RFOCUS, B)).Value = Worksheets(3).Range(Cells(RECORD, A)).Value 'copies focus EmpID to destination
wb.Worksheets(TFOCUS).Range(Cells(4, CFOCUS)).Value = Worksheets(3).Range(Cells(RECORD, B)).Value 'copies focus Course to destination
wb.Worksheets(TFOCUS).Range(Cells(RFOCUS, CFOCUS)).Value = Worksheets(3).Range(Cells(RECORD, C)).Value 'copies focus Date to destination
CFOCUS = CFOCUS + 1 'moves focus to next column
RECORD = RECORD + 1 'creates next record

'save [wb] workbook? Close it?
Set wb = Nothing
```

May I also suggest to keep `YELLCASE` for constants, and to use `camelCase` for locals and `PascalCase` for everything else?

Comment: Thanks Matts Mug, been a few years since I have coded and have forgotten a lot of conventions and syntax. Also, fairly new to VBA for excel. Will give this a go on Monday, and sort out my variable names too!

Thanks for your help so far and have a fantastic Easter weekend!

Answer (score 0):

If RFOCUS is set to "Q" and B and A are integers, then this:

```
FILEPATH.Worksheets(TFOCUS).Range(Cells(RFOCUS, B)).Value = Worksheets(3).Range(Cells(RECORD, A)).Value
```

should be:

```
FILEPATH.Worksheets(TFOCUS).Range(RFOCUS & B).Value = Worksheets(3).Cells(Record, A).Value
```

Here are all 3 lines:

```
FILEPATH.Worksheets(TFOCUS).Range(RFOCUS & B).Value = Worksheets(3).Cells(Record, A).Value
FILEPATH.Worksheets(TFOCUS).Cells(4, CFOCUS).Value = Worksheets(3).Cells(Record, B).Value
FILEPATH.Worksheets(TFOCUS).Range(RFOCUS & CFOCUS).Value = Worksheets(3).Cells(Record, C).Value
```

Comment: Economist, thanks for pointing out - actually, I have RFOCUS and CFOCUS the wrong way around - RFOCUS is the row that the script is working on, CFOCUS is the columns. Therefore, when RFOCUS is set to 5, I am referencing cell 5B. When CFOCUS is set to Q, I am referencing cell 4Q. I shall edit my question to reflect this. Should I be referencing as **CFOCUS, B**, **CFOCUS & B**, **CFOCUS, "B"**, or **CFOCUS & B**? Similarly, should numbers be as **4**, or **"4"**?

Thanks for your help so far and have a fantastic Easter weekend!

Comment: Make sure to reference cells, column then row like B5, and I think that will help you. So if CFOCUS is set to "Q" and you want cell Q4 you would say:     `CFOCUS = "Q"` and     `worksheets(3).range(CFOCUS & 5).value`